Argocd Image updater not updating my deployment
I am using argocd image updater in my AKS. I gave below tags in my application file
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: develop-argo
  namespace: argocd
  finalizers:
  - resources-finalizer.argocd.argoproj.io
  annotations:
    argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/image-list: sessionservice=acr.azurecr.io/session_micro
    argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/sessionservice.update-strategy: semver
    argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/sessionservice.pull-secret: pullsecret:argocd/acr
    argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/write-back-method: argocd
spec:
  project: default
  source:
    repoURL: https://github.com/Deloitte-US-Consulting/SFL_Endeavor_TerraformDeployment.git
    targetRevision: development
    path: helm-charts/
    helm:
      valueFiles:
      - values.yaml
  destination:
    server: 'https://kubernetes.default.svc'
    namespace: dev
  syncPolicy:
    automated:
      prune: false
      selfHeal: true

I deployed with image version: v1.0.0, After that I created new image with version v1.0.1, In the image updater logs I got message
level=info msg="Successfully updated image 'acr.azurecr.io/session_micro:v1.0.0' to 'acr.azurecr.io/session_micro:v1.0.1', but pending spec update (dry run=false)" alias=sessionservice application=develop-argo image_name=session_micro image_tag=v1.0.0 registry=acr.azurecr.io
time="2024-10-08T16:37:56Z" level=debug msg="Using commit message: "
time="2024-10-08T16:37:56Z" level=info msg="Committing 1 parameter update(s) for application develop-argo" application=develop-argo
time="2024-10-08T16:37:56Z" level=info msg="Successfully updated the live application spec" application=develop-argo
time="2024-10-08T16:37:56Z" level=info msg="Processing results: applications=1 images_considered=1 images_skipped=0 images_updated=1 errors=0"

Even though logs show them succeeded my deployment is still using v1.0.0 I dont understand whats going on. Everything looks fine even in logs it is saying it picket up. Is there any mistake I am doing since it is not able to create images with new version?

I am able to resolve issue when I added annotations
argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/session1.helm.image-tag: <>
argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/session1.helm.image-name:<>

